# Marketing Cloud data views for Journeys that do not send emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, journeybuilder, data-views

**Background**

My customer would like to create non-sending journey to get a better sense of the data coming into a journey, and decision logic we plan to use. We are experiencing lots of bad/dirty data, thus many journeys have not flowed as expected.  We have no control over the data and plan to use Salesforce Entry points to trigger the journeys from the CRM as they should be.

I typically use the Update a DE activity to audit my journeys, but that fails b/c we are creating a new contact key when we inject contacts in the journey from the SFDC entry source.

**Problem**

My proposed solution is to build a few queries off of the the data views. In my research of Journey Dataviews, I hit a roadblock. Per documentation " JourneyActivityObjectID corresponds to TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID in the _Sent, _Open, _Click, and _Bounce, data views."

**Ask**

Does anyone have any thoughts or secret workarounds that I can use to see what contacts have entered a journey and hit my "wait" activities?  Since the Journey History Tab shows this, I feel this should be accessible somehow.

Comment: Dataviews only relate to email sends -- nothing else.  You'll have to use the Update Contact activity to log other non-email related events.

Comment: Check this out: https://gortonington.com/journey-history-for-last-30-days-via-api/

Comment: Thanks @zuzannamj

Comment: thanks @AdamSpriggs

Comment: I outline my go-to method for journey logging here: https://sprignaturemoves.com/journey-logging-using-update-contact/

Comment: @AdamSpriggs in your solution ^^ you write  "Journey_Builder_Status Data Extension.  The Update Contact activity writes to this Data Extension." - I have found that the JB Update Contact Activity fails if the Subscriber Key is missing from the DE you are trying to update (IE "Journey_Builder_Status") .  Does mapping the DE in Contact Builder solve this?  thanks

Comment: Yes, that would work.  Update Contact can only update DEs linked in Contact Builder (which is outlined in my blog post).

Comment: Thank you @AdamSpriggs